getting invalid Hook call despite using a hook inside functional component
Hi this is a next js app with Axios, TanstackQuery. I'm trying to re-route to "/login" page in case of a 401 that is caught by AxiosInterCeptorIntance. React version 18, react-dom version 18, React 14.1.3
It is throwing an error at the usage of useRouter of next/navigation
import axios from "axios";
import { RedirectType, redirect, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";

const AxiosInterceptorInstance = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const axiosInterceptorInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  });

  // Request interceptor
  axiosInterceptorInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("auth_token");
      if (accessToken) {
        if (config.headers)
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  // Response interceptor
  axiosInterceptorInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
          toast.error(`${error.response.data.message}`, {
            duration: 4500,
          });
          router.push("/login");
          break;

        case 422:
          toast.error(`${error.response.data.errors[0]}`, {
            duration: 2500,
          });
          break;

        case 500:
          toast.error("something went wrong", {
            duration: 2500,
          });
          break;

        default:
          toast.error(`${error.response.statusText} | ${error.message}`);
          break;
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  return { axiosInterceptorInstance };
};

export default AxiosInterceptorInstance;



Tried redirect of next js, not getting syntax error but not re-routing either
Tried window.location = "/login", falling in an infinite loopenter image description here


You'll have to show the full error message

Hi i took SS, but forgot to add. Now I'v added it. plz check

This isn't a React component, it doesn't return JSX. So you can't use hooks inside it.

Does this answer your question? React router v6 how to use `navigate` redirection in axios interceptor

but the same style is working in another next js app with same tool TanStack Query, Axios
const Instance = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const token = getToken();
  
  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
          router.push('/login')
          break;
        //.
        default:
          break;
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );
  return { instance, serverInstance };
};


@GuyIncognito

@phil no unfortunately

Then you'll have to show how you're using this function. You've essentially created a new hook instead of a component so you have to use it as a hook.

import { z } from "zod";
import ProdFormSchema from "@/lib/AddProdSchema";
import AxiosInterceptorInstance from "./axiosInterceptorInstance";

type ProductSchema = z.infer<typeof ProdFormSchema>;

const useProductService = () => {
  const { axiosInterceptorInstance } = AxiosInterceptorInstance();

  const addProduct = async (data: any) => {
    const res = await axiosInterceptorInstance.post("products", data);
    return res.data;
  };

  return {
    addProduct,
  };
};

export default useProductService;


@GuyIncognito

Edit the question. The comments are unreadable.

You can't use hooks outside of React hooks or React components.
You can use event bus to emit router, for eaxmple:
// event-bus.ts
import type { AppRouterInstance } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime';

import eventemitter from 'eventemitter3';

export const eventBus = eventemitter();

export const push = (path: string) => {
  eventBus.emit('router-push', path);
}

export const subscribe = (router: AppRouterInstance) => {
   const onPush = (path: string) => {
      router.push(path);
    }
    eventBus.on('router-push', onPush);
    return () => {
      eventBus.off('router-push', onPush);
    }
}

'use client'
 
// Create SetupRouterListener.tsx 
// Then add this component to your Layout.tsx

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { eventBus, subscribe } from './event-bus';

export default function SetupRouterListener() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    return subscribe(router);
  }, [router]);

  return null
}

Finally with some improvement:
import axios from "axios";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { push } from './event-bus';

const isBrowser = typeof document !== 'undefined';

const AxiosInterceptorInstance = () => {

  const axiosInterceptorInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  });

  // Request interceptor
  axiosInterceptorInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const accessToken = isBrowser ? localStorage.getItem("auth_token") : '';
      if (accessToken) {
        if (config.headers)
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  // Response interceptor
  axiosInterceptorInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
          toast.error(`${error.response.data.message}`, {
            duration: 4500,
          });
          push("/login");
          break;

        case 422:
          toast.error(`${error.response.data.errors[0]}`, {
            duration: 2500,
          });
          break;

        case 500:
          toast.error("something went wrong", {
            duration: 2500,
          });
          break;

        default:
          toast.error(`${error.response.statusText} | ${error.message}`);
          break;
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  return { axiosInterceptorInstance };
};

export default AxiosInterceptorInstance;


Hey, thnx. I will try n let u know

will SetupRouterListener.tsx affect folder based navigation that comes with next js ?
@JeremySu

SetupRouterListener is a component, use into your root layout

Hi, I tried it previously inside a custom hook like useAxiosInstanceInterceptor.ts but it still threw invalid hook call error.

const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const instance = () => {}
  //..
  return {instance}
}


Did you try my code? Your hooks should use inside react components.

Hi, I tried. And wrapped the root layout with SetupRouterListener.tsx and also installed the eventemitter3 package. It didn't throw any error. but didn't work either.
There may be other reasons I'm not sure,

Do you have code in Github, I can give a check if you don't mind
